# Unable to delete files in Temporary Internet Files folder

Tags: windows-7

I'm on Win7. I have a large number of of large .bin files, totaling 183GB, in my Temporary Internet Files folder. They all seem to come from video sharing sites like youtube. The files are invisible in Explorer even after allowing viewing of hidden files. The only way I can see them is by issuing "dir /fs" on the command line. Now when I try to delete them from the command line nothing happens. Trying to delete the whole folder from Explorer results in access denied because another process is using a file in the folder (IE is not running while I'm doing this). Trying to clear the folder using IE is also unsuccessful.

1. How do I delete these files?
2. How did they end up being there without being deleted by IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some options that you could try .

1. Download [unlocker](http://www.filehippo.com/es/download_unlocker/) and try to use that
   it should also show which process is locking the file
2. Try running the cdm as admin and then try to delete the files
3. [Enable admin account](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/enable-the-hidden-administrator-account-on-windows-vista/) in our machine and then login as an admin and delete the files
4. Login in safe mode and delete them .

Answer (score 1):

[CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER) is good at getting rid of temporary files and other junk. I even set it in Task Scheduler to launch every few hours. You can also, inside the program, define that you want to clean up at system start.

To see the files, you have not only set `Display hidden files` but uncheck `Hide protected operating system files` (in XP, in 7 should be similar). You can also use [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) or other software like that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Great question. This isn't just a "Go to internet options and delete all" type of thing.

The reason you cannot see ALL the files inside TIF (Temporary Internet Files) even with hiddens and system protecteds* shown, is because you are logged in under the same user account that has that TIF folder. If you create another admin account (call it USER2), then you can look into

```
c:...\user1\appdata\local\microsoft\windows\temporary internet files
```

and see the folders and filed which are user1is banned from seeing. Then you can delete as necessary. I think it's ridiculous how large this TIF can grow, and it cannot be controlled by browsers. None of my browsers have free-reign on their temp storage.

- this phrase means that Showing Hidden files and Unhiding System Proteced files DOES NOT do you any good in the TIF folder if you are viewing the TIF folder for the user account you are also logged in as, even if you are an Admin logged in uder Safe Mode.